# Was Shahrabanoo, the daughter of Yazdgerd III, really the wife of Hossein Ibn Ali?

Tags: islam, persia, iran

I am planning to write a historical story about ancient Iran and I have encountered a problem whether [Shahrbanoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahrbanu) the daughter of [Yazdgerd III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yazdegerd_III), the last king of Iran, was the wife of Hossein Ibn Ali and the fourth imam of the Shiites.
According to Persian language books, this theory is correct, but most of the sources of the 3rd century AH consider Hossein Ibn Ali's wife to be a captive of Sindh state from Pakistan.
Which version is correct?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786); I've added Wikipedia links that seem to contradict the thesis.  Please reconcile & revise

Comment: Voting to close as trivial... The first link directly states that she's "allegedly one of the wives".... Note "allegedly", so we probably don't know for sure. Note "one of the wives", where the question seems to assume without basis that he only had one wife. If there's still an answerable question to resolve here please edit.

Comment: @Parisa P.m  There are many cases where one or more historical sources claim that there was a specific genealogical relationship between two persons, but it is contradicted by other sources, or the sources are so long after the era that they might not have correct information and might have made it up.  In a case of a genealogical controversy in history, a fiction writer is free to choose the answer which works best for their story.  I discuss this and other details in post number 5 in  https://historum.com/t/emperor-maurice-and-khosrow-ii-of-persia.127393/

Comment: @Parisa P.m     See  https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/66838/when-were-yazdegerd-iii-and-peroz-iii-born  for a discussion of  controversies about the possible relationship between Yazdgerd III and Hussein.